# Convert 2 byte from byte array to one integer

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, type-conversion

I have a list of `bytearray`s that looks like that :

```
data = [
   bytearray(b'\x01'),
   bytearray(b'\x03'),
   bytearray(b'\x04'),
   bytearray(b'\x01'),
   bytearray(b'\x05'),
   bytearray(b'\x00'),
   bytearray(b'\xC0'),
   bytearray(b'\xfa'),
   bytearray(b'3')
]
```

This array is what I read from a sensor. What I need is to uses `data[3]` and `data[4]` together (so `01 05` ) to convert this into an integer (should be 261) to get a value from the sensor. I struggle to do it. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int` provides an alternative constructor for this:

```
>>> int.from_bytes(data[3] + data[4], 'big')
261
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
data[3][0] * 256 + data[4][0]
```

or

```
data[3][0] << 8 | data[4][0]
```

Answer (score 2):

A readable solution would be:

```
temp = data[3] + data[4]
r = int.from_bytes(temp, byteorder='big', signed=False)
```

Combining the bytearrays and using the from_bytes method to create an integer (which is indeed 261 with byteorder 'big' and unsigned).